# Play Slick version 1.0.1, how to generate the SQL from models?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I am looking at this example:

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/computer-database

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database/app/dao/CompaniesDAO.scala

How can I generate the SQL (DDL) file for applying to the database for this example?

I tried in application.conf
ebean.default="models.daos.*"

This didn't help. Also I don't see any examples within that github https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/ which generate SQL from the models.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but the idea of Slick generator is to generate **models** from DB schema, not other way around.

Comment: I was previously generating database schema from my models somehow like this before in an earlier version of play-slick with slick but not with play-slick-evolutions.

Comment: In the example you linked, db schema is created from evolutions. You will find them under `conf/evolutions` dir.